# Drag and Drop position? How to use rectangle? WinForms, C#

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

Drag and Drop in winform returns the dropped on top-leftmost on its Drop. Or to make it clear, it drops where the cursor of the mouse is. I know I have to add some of the codes like the rectangle. But im new in this drag and drop function. Can someone help me pls? Here's my code:

```
private void label1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   label1.DoDragDrop(label1, DragDropEffects.Move);           
}

private void panel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
   label1.Location = this.panel1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
}

private void panel1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
   e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what are trying to achieve, can you explain please?

Comment: Yes, what's the question?  Help with what exactly?

Comment: for example, i target the drag in the middle of the label, it drops the topleftmost of the label where the cursor is.

Comment: I understand that part, but what would you like it to do instead?  Where should it go?  What do you expect that is not happening?

Comment: lets say i click it in the middle of the label and then drag, after dropping, i want the cursor of the mouse still in the middle of the label and not at the top-leftmost of the label.

Comment: I think it has something to do with this:
    label1.Location = this.panel1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

Comment: Ive tried this one and it drops in the middle of the label. Its like this but its not what I want to happen: label1.Location = this.panel1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X - label1.Width/2, e.Y - label1.Height/2));

Comment: Ok here its like this. Consider dragging in WinForm Design. When we drag a control, it drops where I point (using the mouse) the drag.

Comment: Anyway I found it. Heres the link I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703132/c-sharp-moving-a-control-to-the-mouses-position

Answer (score 1):

It's at the top left because `label1.Location = this.panel1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));` sets the position of the top left. Try getting the location of the mouse relative to the dragged item and subtracting those coordinates.

```
private void panel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
   //Gives you the position of the mouse relative to the top left of panel1
   point offset = e.GetPosition(panel1); 
   label1.Location = this.panel1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X-offset.X, e.Y-offset.Y));
}
```